# updating - codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

When updating the user's details, the database will update all the information, although when the page refreshes, the previous information is showing and it does not update unless the user has logged out and logged back in. I am new to CodeIgniter. Could someone please help me or tell me what to do, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

This is my Model:

```
function updateAccount($submit_userid, $submit_phone, $submit_address, $submit_eaddress) {

    $this->db->where("intMemberID", $submit_userid);
    $this->db->update("tblMembers", array(
        "strPhoneNumber" => $submit_phone,
        "strMemberAddress" => $submit_address,
        "strEmailAddress" => $submit_eaddress,
    ));
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
class UpdateController extends CI_Controller {

public function updateAccount() {

    $this->load->model('userModel');

    $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata('userobject');

    $submit_userid = $this->input->post('userid');
    $submit_phone = $this->input->post('phone');
    $submit_address = $this->input->post('address');
    $submit_eaddress = $this->input->post('eaddress');

    $this->userModel->updateAccount($submit_userid, $submit_phone, $submit_address, $submit_eaddress);

    $this->load->view('updateView', $data);
}

}
```

Comment: What is `$this->session->userdata('userobject')` and where is it populated???

Comment: The data you are sending to the view was retrieved before the update, try getting the userdata after the update

Answer (score 0):

because you show the old data obtained from the last session. read data directly from database and show it in the view

Answer (score 0):

Your user data is being fetched from the session, rather than the database, you have :

```
$data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata('userobject');
```

This data is put into the session on user login, most likely, thus your problem. You need to change source of the data to

```
$data['userdata'] = $this->userModel->returnAccount($this->user_id);
```

or whatever method you have for retrieving the data, to fetch it from your database. Do you have any returnAccount methods in your model? I assume you are not the one who wrote it.